# Upload files to Azure Storage from Azure VM

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have some code in Node.JS that takes file from user and uploads it to my blob storage.

I am using `azure-storage` package with this code:

```
blobSvc.createBlockBlobFromLocalFile('t-uploads', 'high/' + file.name, './tmp/storage/' + file.name, function(error, result, response) {
            console.log("did come here", error, result, response);
            if (!error) {
                console.log(response);
                fs.unlink('./tmp/storage/' + file.name);
            } else {
                console.log(error);
                next(new Error("Azure High Resolution Error!"));
            }
        });
```

the thing is that the code works when i run it from c9.io but does not run when I use the same code on my azure VM.

log (from Azure VM):

```
trumptcore-2 at auth
trumptcore-2 upload authed
trumptcore-2 at rename: baracuda new.jpg
trumptcore-2 after remote
trumptcore-2 { files: { files: [ [Object] ] }, fields: {} }
trumptcore-2 { container: 'storage',
trumptcore-2   name: '3736f0ab_baracuda new.jpg',
trumptcore-2   type: 'image/jpeg',
trumptcore-2   originalFilename: 'baracuda new.jpg',
trumptcore-2   size: 30065 }
trumptcore-2 it is image
trumptcore-2 outside resize
trumptcore-2 Web server listening at: http://0.0.0.0:3000
trumptcore-2 Browse your REST API at http://0.0.0.0:3000/explorer
```

no errors as such but my node api restarts

log (from c9.io):

```
Web server listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080
Browse your REST API at http://0.0.0.0:8080/explorer
at auth
upload authed
at rename: baracuda.jpg
after remote
{ files: { files: [ [Object] ] }, fields: {} }
{ container: 'storage',
  name: 'e1ddeb85_baracuda.jpg',
  type: 'image/jpeg',
  originalFilename: 'baracuda.jpg',
  size: 30400 }
outside resize
{ isSuccessful: true,
  statusCode: 201,
  body: '',
  headers: 
   { 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
     'content-md5': 'NwLTR4gRnN/6GyPETR5MWw==',
     'last-modified': 'Sun, 28 Aug 2016 11:33:43 GMT',
     etag: '"0x8D3CF372A628D41"',
     server: 'Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0',
     'x-ms-request-id': '65eb3380-0001-00a5-2020-01fdd4000000',
     'x-ms-version': '2015-12-11',
     'x-ms-request-server-encrypted': 'false',
     date: 'Sun, 28 Aug 2016 11:33:43 GMT',
     connection: 'close' },
  md5: undefined }
{ isSuccessful: true,
  statusCode: 201,
  body: '',
  headers: 
   { 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
     'content-md5': 'bX2AWHEjxMY2r5yta2ChIQ==',
     'last-modified': 'Sun, 28 Aug 2016 11:33:43 GMT',
     etag: '"0x8D3CF372A90378B"',
     server: 'Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0',
     'x-ms-request-id': 'e1cbc742-0001-010a-3f20-019911000000',
     'x-ms-version': '2015-12-11',
     'x-ms-request-server-encrypted': 'false',
     date: 'Sun, 28 Aug 2016 11:33:43 GMT',
     connection: 'close' },
  md5: undefined }
```

**Update**

i tried this code at location where it all fails

```
fs = require('fs')
        fs.readFile('./tmp/storage/' + file.name, 'utf8', function (err,data) {
          if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
          }
          console.log(data);
        });
```

I can hence read the files successfully on both azure vm and c9.io. so probably not permissions issue on local.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Can you share those error details?

Comment: @GauravMantri added logs please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok sorry for the troubles, it was the dumb pm2 that was restarting my application when the upload was complete.